# how to translate the path of svg

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg-animate

I have a svg of speedometer. I want to create some animation. There is a needle which is made of path. I have grouped that path so that i can translate or transform. Its a meter/needle which has to move with the user provided value. If the user provides the value between 0 and 25, the needle should be in first slice and so on. But i have no idea on moving the needle which is made of path.

I have created a jsbin of it

http://jsbin.com/danefehiro/1/edit?html,js,output

Here is the code

```
<input type="text" id="speedValue" />
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 344.996 344.996" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <path fill="rgb(132, 219, 255)" d="M7.5,243.337h52.227c0-31.141,12.622-59.334,33.03-79.741l-36.93-36.93
        C25.968,156.525,7.5,197.774,7.5,243.337z"/>
    <path fill="rgb(84, 192, 235)" d="M55.827,126.666l36.93,36.93c20.408-20.408,48.6-33.03,79.741-33.03V78.339
        C126.935,78.339,85.685,96.807,55.827,126.666z"/>
    <circle style="fill:#51B3DA;" cx="172.498" cy="243.337" r="23.32"/>
    <path fill="rgb(255, 209, 92)" d="M337.496,243.337h-52.227c0-31.141-12.622-59.334-33.03-79.741l36.93-36.93
        C319.028,156.525,337.496,197.774,337.496,243.337z"/>
    <path fill="rgb(255, 112, 88)" d="M289.169,126.666l-36.93,36.93c-20.408-20.408-48.6-33.03-79.741-33.03V78.339
        C218.061,78.339,259.311,96.807,289.169,126.666z"/>
    <g id="meter">
        <path fill="#40596B" id="needle" d="M175.884,220.29c10.162,1.482,18.179,9.5,19.661,19.662l44.785-64.447L175.884,220.29z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>


  var speedValue = document.querySelector('#speedValue');
  var needle = document.querySelector('#needle');
  var meter = document.querySelector('#needle');
  speedValue.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var value = event.target.value;
    // if value is in between 1 - 25, the needle
    // should be on first block, if 25 - 50, then
    // the needle should be on second slice and if
    // 50  - 75, then on 3rd slice and if 75 - 100
    // then on last slice
    if (value >= 0 && value <= 25) {
      meter.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(45)");
    } else if(value > 25 && value <= 50) {
      meter.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(90)"); 
    } else {
      meter.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(180)"); 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You laid a trap for yourself when the #meter path by default is already rotating 135 degrees, and you are missing a transform-origin for the diagram. The following works:

```
var speedValue = document.querySelector('#speedValue');
var needle = document.querySelector('#needle');
var meter = document.querySelector('#meter');
speedValue.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var value = event.target.value;
  // if value is in between 1 - 25, the needle
  // should be on first block, if 25 - 50, then
  // the needle should be on second slice and if
  // 50  - 75, then on 3rd slice and if 75 - 100
  // then on last slice
  needle.setAttribute("transform-origin", "172.498px 243.337px");
  if (value >= 0 && value <= 25) {
    needle.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-112.5)"); // 45 / 2 - 135 = -112.5
  } else if(value > 25 && value <= 50) {
    needle.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-67.5)"); 
  } else if(value > 50 && value <= 75) {
    needle.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-22.5)"); 
  } else {
    needle.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(22.5)"); 
  }
});
```

I added an onLoad listener to correctly orient the needle from the start.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
  var value = event.target.value;
  needle.setAttribute("transform-origin", "172.498px 243.337px");
  needle.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(-112.5)");
});
```

---

According to the comments, an animateTransform element is added to show you how to use it (even though it should belong to a new question).

A new jsbin: http://jsbin.com/qexohozido/1/edit?html,js,output

First you add the element under #needle:

```
<animateTransform id="animation" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 172.498 243.337" to="0 172.498 243.337" dur="1s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive"/>
```

Then you animate it inside your if-else:

```
var from = 0;
var animation = document.querySelector('#animation');
... else if(value > 50 && value <= 75) {
  animation.setAttribute("from", from + " 172.498 243.337");
  animation.setAttribute("to", "90 172.498 243.337");
  animation.beginElement();
  from = 90; 
} ...
```

In this case you need not offset -135 degrees in #animation because the rotation is already being offset in #needle during onLoad.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What is the way to calculate the perfect degree to move? How could you know that -112.5 degree exactly falls on the first slice and etc? Is there any mathematical calculation? I come from a management faculty so its a difficult to understand the animation part like translate, transform.

Comment: Your speedometer is divided into 4 segments across 180 degrees, so you got it right that each segment is 180 / 4 = 45 degrees. But I suppose you want to point it to the center of each segment, and half a segment is 45 / 2 = 22.5 degrees. Since the graphics of the meter needle starts at 135 degrees, you'd have to subtract 135 degrees for everything. Hence for the first segment, the needle points to 22.5 - 135 = -112.5 degrees. Thereafter +45 degrees for each subsequent segment.

Comment: The transform-origin is set according to the circle's center connecting the needle.
 *<circle style="fill:#51B3DA;" cx="172.498" cy="243.337" r="23.32"/>* By the way don't forget to accept my answer using the check mark if it works!

Comment: Thanks for explanation. If i want to use animateTransform element of svg, then the from should be "172.498, 243.337" ? What should be the value of to? If it should be given degree, then i understand but unaware about origin like from value.

Comment: Why don't you tryout the code yourself? ;) For your reference I've added <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 172.498 243.337" to="360 172.498 243.337" dur="10s" repeatDur="indefinite"/> to the code and you can observe the result. http://jsbin.com/pigefujane/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The value that i provided were not working. I have to provide the value randomly to see which works. That's the reason i wanted to take the tip on understanding the algorithm behind the calculation of x, y and degrees. I have marked this as worked and helpful. Thanks again

Comment: By the way... http://jsbin.com/losapicixo/1/edit?html,js,output Changed the listener back to on click because with animation "keyup" will look weird.